# TemplateNotFound Error in Flask App: index.html Not Found

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I am facing an issue while setting up a simple Flask application to create a web page. When I run the application and access it in the browser, I receive an error message

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html
```

The directory structure of my project is as follows:

```
├── app.py
├── templates
│   └── index.html
└── ...
```

I have checked and confirmed that the "index.html" file is indeed placed within the "templates" directory and the file name is spelled correctly.

Here is the source code of the "app.py" file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And here is the content of the "index.html" file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title>Intelligent Processing System</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Intelligent Processing System</h1>
 Other content of the web page -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I am using Flask version 2.3.2.

I tried running a Flask application with the expectation that the "index.html" file would be successfully rendered when accessing the application in the browser. However, I encountered the error "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html".

I have double-checked the directory structure and file names, and everything seems to be in order. The "index.html" file is located in the "templates" directory, and the file name is spelled correctly.

I expected that when I accessed the application in the browser, the web page would display the content defined in the "index.html" file. However, the error mentioned above occurred instead.

Comment: Please provide full exception

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and it works as expected on my machine. Maybe triple check the spelling and make sure there are no extra characters or whitespace in the names of `index.html` and the `templates` directory.